# FIND_IN_SET - Getting partial output due to doubled values

Tags: sql, mysql, recursive-query, find-in-set

Table "**skus**":

| plant_species_ids |
| --- |
| 1,2,3,2,3,1 |

Table "**plant_species**"

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Plant 1 |
| 2 | Plant 2 |
| 3 | Plant 3 |

The relevant part of my MySQL code:

```
...
GROUP_CONCAT(plant_species.name SEPARATOR ', ') as plant_species_names
...
LEFT JOIN plant_species 
       ON FIND_IN_SET(plant_species.id, skus.plant_species_ids) > 0
```

Output I get:

```
Plant 1,Plant 2,Plant 3
```

Result I need to get:

```
Plant 1,Plant 2,Plant 3, Plant 2,Plant 3,Plant 1
```

From what I can tell it's acting like I'm using DISTINCT when I'm not.

Any ideas how to do this?

---

Edit

Here is my final code for anyone else that has this same problem:
``

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.customer_id, orders.invoice_amount, orders.delivery_date, orders.delivery_time, GROUP_CONCAT(skus.name SEPARATOR ', ') as sku_name, orders.sku_ids as sku_ids, orders.sku_weights as sku_weights

FROM orders

JOIN json_table(concat('[',orders.sku_ids,']'), '$[*]' columns (id int path '$')) AS species_ids

LEFT JOIN skus on skus.id=species_ids.id
WHERE orders.id=10
GROUP BY orders.id;
```

``

Comment: much easier to answer if you provide create table and full select statements (even if you make up the other parts of it)

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  how many ids at most will there be in plant_species_ids?

Comment: @ysth - 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way is to wrap your ids column in brackets and expand it using json_table, but I'm not sure how to do that as a left join.

```
select skus.id, GROUP_CONCAT(plant_species.name SEPARATOR ', ') as plant_species_names
from skus
join json_table(concat('[',skus.plant_species_ids,']'), '$[*]' columns (id int path '$')) as species_ids
left join plant_species on plant_species.id=species_ids.id
group by skus.id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x-8SS_WP)

The original select doesn't find the later duplicate ids because the join is only comparing skus rows to plant_species rows, not the individual ids in plant_species_ids, and find_in_set will find only the first instance of a plant_species id in plant_species_ids.

Comment: Using `JSON_TABLE` was very brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL 8.0, you may use a recursive query to unnest all your comma separated "*plant_species_ids*" data:

- base step: compute the length of your string, by counting the commas
- recursive step: extract your values among commas, one at each step, using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and decreasing an integer index

Stop the recursion once the index has reached 0. Then you can join your unnested table with the "*plant_species*" table, and apply aggregation.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT plant_species_ids,
           '-1' AS element,
           CHAR_LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(plant_species_ids, '[^,]', ''))+1 AS num_elements
    FROM skus
  
    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT plant_species_ids, 
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(plant_species_ids, ',', num_elements), ',', -1),
           num_elements - 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE num_elements > 0
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ps.name ORDER BY cte.num_elements) AS plants
FROM       cte
INNER JOIN plant_species ps
        ON cte.element = ps.id
WHERE cte.element > 0
```

**Output**:

| plants |
| --- |
| Plant 1,Plant 2,Plant 3,Plant 2,Plant 3,Plant 1 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/syoLSGgMhAAnTw4kjM7yB5/2).

Note: As a general consideration, it's better not to store data as comma-separated values, as it's very difficult to apply data manipulation on such kind of data, and typically need to employ quite inefficient and ugly queries to deal with it.

Comment: That does work, thank you!

It is rather complicated. Is there any way to simplify it?

Comment: It's the price of having comma-separated-valued fields, as stated in the note. You can't do much about this complexity unluckily.